# alert dialog is not appearing flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build function that take values from user and alert him if he had high , low or normal blood pressure so , I did this

```
void preesureRanges(double sysValue, double diaValue) {
    String text = "";

    if (sysValue >= 120 &&
        sysValue <= 130 &&
        diaValue >= 80 &&
        diaValue <= 90) {
      text = ("معدل ضغط الدم في الجسم طبيعي");
    } else if (sysValue < 120 && diaValue < 80) {
      text =
          ("معدل ضغط الدم منخفض \nالرجاء تناول طعام مالح وشرب كمية كافية من الماء ");
    } else if (sysValue > 130 && diaValue > 90) {
      text = ("معدل ضغط الدم مرتفع  ");
    }
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text(
            text,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Buttons(
                height: 35,
                width: 100,
                text: 'اغلاق',
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

but the alert dialog is not showing up I tried to invoke the method and the method is working correctly
after that I tried to change and I put the invoke of the alert inside the if like this

```
void preesureRanges(double sysValue, double diaValue) {
    String text = "";

    if (sysValue >= 120 &&
        sysValue <= 130 &&
        diaValue >= 80 &&
        diaValue <= 90) {
      showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(
              "معدل ضغط الدم في الجسم طبيعي",
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Buttons(
                  height: 35,
                  width: 100,
                  text: 'اغلاق',
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      text = ("معدل ضغط الدم في الجسم طبيعي");
    } else if (sysValue < 120 && diaValue < 80) {
      text =
          ("معدل ضغط الدم منخفض \nالرجاء تناول طعام مالح وشرب كمية كافية من الماء ");
    } else if (sysValue > 130 && diaValue > 90) {
      text = ("معدل ضغط الدم مرتفع \nالرجاء مدري والله ايش المفروض تسوي ");
    }
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text(
            text,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Buttons(
                height: 35,
                width: 100,
                text: 'اغلاق',
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

but here only the first case is showing the alert , I also tried to but the invoke of the alert in every case but no thing is showed

```
 onPreesed: () {
          preesureRanges(upPressure, downPressure, context);    
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
```

here is the calling if the method, this onPressed is for RaisedButton and i have it inside Bottom Sheet and here is the value that I passed to my function

```
double upPressure;
String upPree;
double downPressure;
String downPree;
```

these tow onChanged function beilong to textFormFiled that I have in bottom sheet

```
 onChanged: (newPrusser) {
              upPree = newPrusser;
              upPressure = double.parse(upPree);
            },
onChanged: (newPrusser) {
          downPree = newPrusser;
          downPressure = double.parse(downPree);
        },
```

Comment: How and where are you calling `preesureRanges`? (typo in pressure?) A little more code could help identify where the problem is. Also check out this: https://coflutter.com/flutter-how-to-show-dialog/

Comment: I am invoking it in the onPressed function of my submit button and passing values from onChanged method of the text filed , I tried to set the method type to be string and I invoked the method in print statement it works correctly

Comment: maybe you're using the wrong context? Try passing it to you method like this: `preesureRanges(BuildContext context, double sysValue, double diaValue)`

Comment: @Er1 I tried you solution but the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error over here:

```dart
onPreesed: () {
          preesureRanges(upPressure, downPressure, context);    
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
```

You have called `Navigator.of(context).pop()` over here. Comment it and you will see that it works.

Comment: I have made a bit of a change. Can you please try that change and let me know if it works? Note: "You will have to pass `context` as a parameter when calling the function.

Comment: Ok. Then, can you share some code where you call the function?

Comment: I have found the cause of the error please check.

Comment: okk this is workkss thanks alot but can you please explain why ?

Comment: Ok. So, when you call a `showDialog()` function, it basically adds a new WIdget to the WIdget tree. So, in order to go back to the main page, if you see you have used `Navigator.of(context).pop()`  in the actions. It removes the Widget from the Widget tree. But if you call it just like that, it will add and remove it simultaneously. So, you won't be able to see it.